# Completeness property of subsets of R

Tags: real-analysis

Given M in R and a non-empty subset S of R, obtain a necessary and sufficient condition for 
 “M is not an upper bound of S”

I tried to prove this with M < x < M+1 for all x in R but it didnt work. Since I'm new to analysis I would appreciate it if someone can show me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to prove. You are asked for a condition logically equivalent to "$M$ is not an upper bound of $S$". You could just use "There is an $s\in S$ such that $s>M$".

Comment: Yeah just figured out from your answer. Thanks alot :)